# paste data from xml file to Excel workbook

Tags: c#, xml, excel, office-interop

I have an xml file which I created by extracting data from an Excel workbook.

http://www.2shared.com/document/wbAYcQ4F/XMLTest.html

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <Styles>
    <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
      <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom" />
      <Borders />
      <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000" />
      <Interior />
      <NumberFormat />
      <Protection />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s16">
      <Borders>
        <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="2" />
        <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="2" />
        <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="2" />
      </Borders>
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s17">
      <Borders>
        <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="2" />
        <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="2" />
      </Borders>
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s18">
      <Borders>
        <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="2" />
        <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="2" />
        <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="2" />
      </Borders>
      <Interior ss:Color="#16365C" ss:Pattern="Solid" />
    </Style>
  </Styles>
  <Worksheet ss:Name="First Worksheet">
    <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="5" ss:ExpandedRowCount="9" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
      <Column ss:Index="3" ss:Width="54" />
      <Row ss:Height="15.75" />
      <Row>
        <Cell ss:Index="3" ss:StyleID="s16">
          <Data ss:Type="Number">12345</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Cell ss:Index="3" ss:StyleID="s17" />
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Cell ss:Index="3" ss:StyleID="s17">
          <Data ss:Type="String">Some Text</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Cell ss:Index="3" ss:StyleID="s17" />
      </Row>
      <Row ss:Height="15.75">
        <Cell ss:Index="3" ss:StyleID="s18" />
      </Row>
    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

The xml file contains data of the range I selected. The worksheet name, and in the range all values, and formatting (colours, borders etc) In this example only column C has a cell with a number, a cell with a string and a coloured cell, plus a border surrounding all data. When you open the file with Excel it shows the data exactly how it's extracted.

Now I want to know if it's possible to extract this as an Excel.Range programmatically with all values and formatting, to paste it into a new Excel Workbook. Preferably without opening the xml file in Excel.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load( "XMLFile1.xml" );

var x= doc.Descendants( "x" );
var y= doc.Descendants( "y" );
object[,] z;
Excel.Application ActiveExelAplication = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application as Excel.Application;
Excel.Worksheet ExWorksheet = ActiveExelAplication.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet;
z= ExWorksheet.get_Range("v"+x[0].ToString() , "v" + y[1].ToString() as Excel.Range;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. Did you download the file? I've edited my initial post with the contents of the xml file, and x and y are not descendants. Also x[0] and y[1] give an error "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.Xelement>"